# Please help with putting an answer together

Tags: discussion

My [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/103287/how-to-name-a-template-file-for-the-following-theme-hook-suggestions#comment121850_103287) apparently solved the issue in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/103287/16495) so it would be a shame if it'll stay unanswered.

On the other hand, I don't quite understand [what exactly OP did with it](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/103287/how-to-name-a-template-file-for-the-following-theme-hook-suggestions#comment121851_103287) and how it worked.

Could anyone please pick these pieces and post CW answer, please? Seems that all the work is done and we need a good editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mołot, here's my suggestion for an answer - feel free to use it:

> It appears that you have non-ASCII characters in your machine names.  That is not a good idea, because they are used in file system constructs and your file system's character set encoding for non-ASCII characters is not necessarily the same as Drupal's internal character set encoding (UTF-8).  Since the machine names are never displayed to users, the simple workaround is to only use ASCII characters in machine names.
>
> Just replace the non-ASCII characters in your machine names with ASCII near equivalent characters (ü → u and so on), and you will not have to guess how to create file names matching your machine names.

(Actually, I am puzzled that he's having this problem.  I run a number of Norwegian sites, and Norwegian has non-ASCII "æøå" - but my Drupal refuses to accept those characters in a machine name.  I pretty sure that this is by default (plain vanilla Drupal 7).